# putting image into background imag e

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have the following code in my Wordpress site

HTML

```
    <div class="test">
            <?php if(has_category( 'update' ) || has_category( 'uncategorized' )) { ?>
                <img alt="icn" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/logo.png"> 
            <?php } elseif(has_category( 'event' )) { ?>
                <img alt="icn" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/logo.png"> 
            <?php } ?>  
    </div>
```

This puts an image in the place of the category name. (category name 'update' = logo.png)

My issue is that I want their sizes responsive since they are going to be put overtop a responsive height div. My idea is to turn them into the background image of the 'test' div. I can't seem to rewrite the img tag code to put them as background images of a div instead of just putting the image itself.

EDIT ex.

```
<?php if(has_category( 'update' ) || has_category( 'uncategorized' )) { ?>
<div style="background-image:url('...');">
...
```

Comment: Try to change your first <img> tag into a <div>

Comment: I tried that, my current attempt is what I added under the edit. I think it'll work if I can find out that to put in the ('...') part

Comment: What did you get when you tried this? Note that you must give your div width and height values (in percentage as it must be responsive), otherwise it won't show anything as its height will be 0.

Comment: I added a padding 10% to test, I am testing it with background-color: red; It shows a red square but no image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this:

```
<div class="test">
<?php if(has_category( 'update' ) || has_category( 'uncategorized' )) { ?>
  <div class="bg-image" style="background-image:url('<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/logo.png');">
<?php } elseif(has_category( 'event' )) { ?>
  <div class="bg-image" style="background-image:url('<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/logo.png');">
<?php } else { ?>
  <div class="bg-image">
<?php } ?>
... Content in div, if necessary ...
</div>
</div>
```

Or, to make it a little cleaner:

```
<?php 
  $testStyle = "";
  if(has_category( 'update' ) || has_category( 'uncategorized' )) {
    $testStyle = "style=\"background-image:url('".get_bloginfo('template_directory')."/img/logo.png')\"";
  } elseif(has_category( 'event' )) {
    $testStyle = "style=\"background-image:url('".get_bloginfo('template_directory')."/img/logo.png')\"";
  }
?>
<div class="test">
  <div class="bg-image" <?php echo $testStyle; ?>></div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
  .bg-image {
    width:100%;
    min-width:300px;
    height:100px;
    background-size:cover;
  }
</style>
```

Realize that if there is nothing inside of the `.bg-image` div, you'll need to add some CSS to make it "visible": a height and width at minimum.

Also, instead of `get_bloginfo('template_directory')`, consider using `get_template_directory_uri()`.

Comment: I have to keep class=test outside, and I tried putting <?php bloginfo inside but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: i think there is some syntax issue, it is printing the text link to my site with no image, not iside the test div either

Comment: still no image. no syntax error. in my original code it references the image correctly and it shows up, but not when I put it as background

Comment: Try forcing the CSS using the CSS I have added to the answer.  If that works, put it in your CSS file, and adjust according to your needs.

Comment: the background is sorta there, so it is targeting, but only a piece of it

Comment: All right, we're on to something.  :)  Try with `background-size:cover;`, which I added to the answer.

Comment: I got it to fit, problem now is that the first one doesn't show. there seems to be a problem with 'update' the post that has that category shows nothing, the ones with 'event' show the background

Comment: fixed it! I had two different path directories to the image. It only works with defined height and width (using px or em) is it possible to use %?

Comment: You can use `%` by giving a `height` of `0`, a `width` of the desired percentage, and a `padding-top` based on the ratio of the picture.  For example: https://jsfiddle.net/thao8xfb/

Comment: can't use 100% width, or it will become the width of the parent

Comment: OK.  The principle should still work no matter the width.  Say 80% and 52% https://jsfiddle.net/thao8xfb/1/  The exact numbers are up to you to decide.